# How to generate pdb files for parallel builds?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-c++, multiprocessing, devenv

We are seeking ideas on resolving a problem with linking/pdb generation when running multiple devenv.com using [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005).

We are getting the following intermittently errors when doing parallel builds using devenv.com.
I.e. when the following get run at the same time on the same build server:

```
devenv.com master.sln /build "Release|Win32" 
devenv.com master.sln /build "Debug|x64" 

fatal error LNK1318: Unexpected PDB error; RPC (23) '(0x000006BA)'
error C2471: cannot update program database
```

We want the [pdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) files, so turning them off isn't realy an option.
Running the builds serially doesn't cause the issue, but of course slows down the build process.

References found so far indicate

- that there are issues with length of file names exceeding the 256 file path limit, this doesn't seem to be our problem as we can build individually, and the path+filename length is around 160 chars.
- there are issues with incremental builds (but mainly in Visual Studio 2008) and we have incremental linking turned off.

We are looking for input on resolving this multiple process issue, if possible.

How do we resolve it?

Comment: I don't think there is a solution to this, but why do you want to perform parallel builds? As far as I know there is enough parallelism in the Visual Studio itself. It will use all available CPU cores on your server while building separate projects and even separate source files in parallel. Somehow the problem with PDB files during this compilation is solved already (if you'll find out how - tell me). Therefore I don't see any reason to run several builds in parallels, since this won't give any benefit unless you have more processor cores that source files in your entire solution :).

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling source-code parallel builds instead. That will efficiently use all cores on your server, unless you have more cores than source files in your solution. Here is more information on how you have enable source-code parallel builds: http://vagus.wordpress.com/2008/02/15/source-level-parallel-build-in-visual-studio-2005/

Comment: All great info especially the link to /MP on 2005. However we actually wish to be able to build more than 1 project at a time (given a 32 core build machine, tend to having most cores idle while linking).  We currently have debug and release versions of projects split to track the project outputs separately, which means there should be no reason not to be able to build both at the same time, except that the pdb link step crashes.

Comment: Not sure this is possible. Visual Studio does some internal management for writes into PDB files when building single project. It does not have any problems, because all write are queued up. However, when you are doing several builds of the same project and they are using same PDB files, there can be problems, because Visual Studio doesn't manage these write across instances of itself, but only within one process. I.e. writes from two devenv.com running in parallels may collide and thus cause one or both builds to fail.

Answer (score 0):

this may be a related problem&solution, because it produces

Unexpected PDB error; RPC (23) '(0x000006BA)'

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/unexpected-pdb-error-rpc-23-0x000006ba/

Comment: Please provide more explanation. The link can also become invalid after some time.

Comment: In older linker versions are problematic .cpp files not containing definitions, only declarations, includes of headers with declarations, empty namespaces, comments,...

Comment: Thanks @Fillippo, though it relates to the Intel (Fortran) compiler, I'll verify if there is a similar issue with Microsoft compiler.